# Are arithmetic operations independent of dimension?

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-functions

A friend of mine claims that in different dimensions, whatever the definition of dimension in any context is, it is possible for 1+1 to not equal 2. Does it matter the dimension one does arithmetic or does 1+1=2 regardless?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by $1$, what you mean by $2$, what you mean by $+$ and what actual context you are attempting to do this "addition" operation in.  For example in $\Bbb F_2$ there are only two numbers, zero and one, and you have $1+1=0$ in that specific context.  In other contexts, like in $\Bbb R^3$ you have $(1,0,0)+(1,0,0)=(2,0,0)$, but you also have things like $(1,0,0)+(0,1,0)=(1,1,0)$ so it isn't clear what you might mean by $1$ and $2$ in the first place.

Comment: @JMoravitz By numbers I mean objects and by addition I mean putting them together. Regardless of base, symbolic representation, or anything else, if I take a single object and another of the same object and put them in a group what quantity of that object will be there?

Comment: That is a horrible way to define addition.  Regardless it still relies on what you mean by "two."  I already gave you an example where 1+1=0, where in that context there isn't an entity we call "two" but you could still choose to define two and you would just end up with 2=0.  If you choose to define "two" it is usually as S(1), the successor of one, i.e. two is generally *defined* as 1+1.  That definition holds whenever it makes sense to add one and one together.